# Mimic SQL Subquery Script with Lambda / LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, t-sql, lambda

I'm trying to mimic a T-SQL script with ASP.NET MVC (Entity Framework) that my lead developer created but then just recently gave resignation and is on other tasks now.

The script is to gather all required information about an item by the last date used and also count how many times it was used. The SQL script groups the IDs, counts the PickIDs associated with that grouped ID, and gathers the latest date:

```
SELECT 
    s.ID, s.ItemCount, s.DateUsed, p.CustNum, p.OrdNum
FROM 
    Tracker as t    
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
         ID, COUNT(PickID) ItemCount, MAX(DateUsed) DateUsed
     FROM 
         Boxes 
     WHERE 
         NOT ID = '1'
     GROUP BY 
         ID) s ON t.ID = s.ID
INNER JOIN 
    Boxes as s2 ON s.ID = s2.ID AND s.DateUsed = s2.DateUsed
INNER JOIN 
    Header as p ON s2.PickID = p.PickID;
```

The given script works perfectly for our auto emailing system, but we need our browser based application to create a file with that exact same information at any given time, not just weekly. I have the file creation and auto emailing, just having a hard time translating it to lambda expressions, LINQ is fine as well.

I've been searching all over stackoverflow and Microsoft's tutorials with little help, so if anyone could point me in the right direction or show and explain how to do it that would be awesome.

Comment: If your query "works perfectly", why are you attempting to re-implement it without (explicitly) using SQL?

Comment: The script is for the auto emailing and of course the warehouse people don't have access to the server except through our browser based application. My boss wants the managers to have the ability to get that information in a file at all times as well.

Comment: So why can't your application execute the query as-is? Or even execute a stored procedure which contains this query?

Comment: Is there no way to use Entity Framework MVC and lambda/LINQ to produce the results of the initial SQL script? Seems to me like writing a lambda or LINQ query would be easier than running the query as-is with our framework. As for the stored procedure, thank you for that suggestion, going forward I will absolutely use this. I still have to follow what my current lead developer asks and that's for lambda / LINQ to run the query.

Answer (score 0):

I enjoy doing this.

```
var p = boxes.GroupBy(x => x.ID).Where(grp => grp.Key != -1)
            .Select(grp => new
            {
                ID = grp.Key,
                ItemCount = grp.Count(),
                DateUsed = grp.Max(x => x.DateUsed)
            });

var q = from x in tracker
        join y in p on x.ID equals y.ID
        join z in boxes on y.ID equals z.ID
        join a in headers on z.PickID equals a.PickID
        select new
        {
            y.ID,
            y.ItemCount,
            DateUser = y.DateUsed,
            a.CustNum,
            a.OrdNum
        };
```